# how to make text content of React-Native be at same level?

Tags: react-native

[image] [image]

The Colon in timer of these two Apps is placed in different places in the orange one which is android  it is a little bit lower than the numbers while the other one which is iPhone it placed at the center or perfectly
so what is causing that and it is the same in every text component and how to make the colon at center?

Comment: perhaps its a different font, try using google font

Comment: can you share your code?